# Change innerHTML of <p> multiple times with only 1 button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to make a step by step instruction and I want the effect to be like when the user clicks on the button which will have the word STEP 1 inside the button the text inside a p element will change to the details on step 1. After that the same button will have the words inside the button changed into STEP 2 and when clicked will change the same p elements contents to step 2 instructions is this possible with javascrpt, jQuery or php??

Comment: jquery is written IN javascript. anything you can do in jquery you can do in "plain" javascript. And yes, you can do this in either. Which one you go with is up to you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? ... As we don't write up code here you have to make an effort of your own and we'll help make that one work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a simple function to do this

```
 <!-- this is the Details Div -->
 <div id="stepDetails"> Step Details Here </div>
 <!-- here is your button that changes with onClick binding -->
 <button id="stepButton" onClick="next_step()"> Step 1 </div>
 <script> 
      /* global arrray with details */
      var step_details = ["Intro Details", "Step 1 Details", "Step 2 Details"];
      /* global variable to track position in array */
      var current_step = 0;

      /* function to be called from onClick binding */
      function next_step() {

              current_step++;   /* increase the step variable */


              document.getElementById("stepDetails").innerHTML = step_details[current_step];


              document.getElementById("stepButton").innerHTML = "Step " + (current_step + 1);
       }

</script>
```

Edit: added some comments to help explain the code better

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I needed!! I could only get it to change the text once and forgot about arrays. I was wondering though if its possible to display images along with the text? in the div#stepDetails?

Comment: Sure -- just include <img> tags in with the step details in the array ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You may do it in various ways. You may use jquery or plain javascript. I would suggest the following logic:

1) You initialize button with first step label and some variable that tracks your steps (e.g. `var step = 1 initial`)

```
<button>Step <span>1</span><button>
```

2) On click you increment variable, get the span in the button and update its content with that variable.

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64uvu6vn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create it with js or jquery(maybe it's better). You can use simply the basis functions like <...onlick="yourfunction()"> to change for the STEPS

'`<script type="text/javascript">
   function youfunction(){`

```
    document.getElementById("p").innnerHTML = 'myDetails';
    .....  


}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just to **increase** array index :

```html
 <body>
 
 
    <div id="div">sample text</div>
    <button id="button" onClick="next_step()"> Step 1 </div>
    
    
    <script> 

      let arr = ["step 1", "step 2", "step 3" , "sample text" ];

      let count = 0; // step

     function next_step() {
     
      if (count < 5) document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = arr[count];
           count++;
      if (count == 4) count = 0; // use 3 for stoping function on the last element
        
        }
   </script>
   
   
  </body>
```

and if you wana make **increase** and **decrease** together , you can use somthing like this  :

```js
"use strict";

let arr = ["index0", "index1", "index2", "index3", "index4"];
let count = 0;
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = arr[0];
function getup() {
  if (count < arr.length) count++;
  if (count === arr.length) count = 0;
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = arr[count];
}
function getdown() {
  if (count >= 0) count--;
  if (count === -1) count = arr.length - 1;
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = arr[count];
}
```

```html
<div id = "div"></div>
<button onclick = "getup()">up</button>
<button onclick= "getdown()">down</button>
```